# Osx 'which' command is not working but strangely. No result / complaint for existing / nonexistent bin?

Tags: flutter, macos, terminal

Below are the results I got for flutter (which I know I have and will work when I run `flutter` by itself, and some random string which I know I don't have. Finally, the `man` command which I know I also have and works. Can anyone explain what might be happening? This is MacOS Monterrey in case it matters.

```
~$ which flutter
~$ which -as flutter
~$ which -as jhsdlkfjhlkjhsdlkfjghlkjhsdfg
~$ which man
/usr/bin/man
```

Comment: This kind of question may be better suited for Stack Overflow's sister sites, superuser.com and unix.stackexchange.com. Here is a similar question on one of them: https://superuser.com/questions/707906 - possible answers there include "the command isn't a program binary but a shell function, and `type` will tell you this".

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there. FYI the flutter docs say `which flutter` should respond with a path and `type flutter` responded with hashed and showed the path to flutter...so I'm still confused but thanks anyway.